# Netty: Keep Server Socket Open After ctx.flush()

Tags: java, netty

I have two servers "A" (built by my friends) and "B" (built by me, using Netty 4.1). this server "A" and "B" would return some response when the client sends a command. I tried to that server using simple JAVA Client Socket. below is the java client code:

```
public class SocketClient
{
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("request.txt").getFile());
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

            System.out.println("Connecting to server:8888");
            Socket socket = new Socket("myserver.com", 8888);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            out.write(content.getBytes());
            out.flush();

            while(true) {
                int response = in.read();
                System.out.println(response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When connect the client to server A (non-netty), the `read()` method give me the output like this:

```
48
48
57
56
48
50
49
48
```

but, when i try to connect to Server "B" (which is using netty), the output is like this:

```
48
48
57
56
48
50
49
48
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

why does this happen? by the way in server B I'm using `ctx.write() and ctx.flush()` and how to make server B get the same behavior with server A (not closing the connection, so it won't return -1)

**edit: Additional Information**

Actually in server "B" i'm using `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` and `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`. After doing some experimentation the problem is on `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`. When i send response using `ctx.writeAndFlush()` from `InboundAdapter`, the socket is not closed. But when the response is passed into `OutboundAdapter` and then i send the response using `ctx.writeAndFlush()` inside `OutboundAdapter` `write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise)` method. The socket is closed

here is the sample of my `OutboundAdapter`:

```
public class OutboundHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OutboundHandler.class);

    //Sending or forwarding message to channel which is already configured
    //condition is depends on which model instance
    //packaging is worked on its packager class
    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception
    {
        String response = "Response form OutboundHandler";
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(response.getBytes()));
    } }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging all-day, i found the root cause of the problem. I accidentally put `ctx.close()` somewhere in my InboundAdapter, so when i pass the message into OutboundAdapter and the flush the message to client it will close the connection

```
try {
   //some code
}
} catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex);
        ErrorData error = new ErrorData();
        error.setCode("99");
        error.setMessage("General System Error");

        //pass the message to OutboundAdapter
        ctx.writeAndFlush(error);
} finally {
  ctx.close();
}
```

So, i just need to remove the `ctx.close()` and the server stopped from closing the socket connection

Answer (score 0):

On Netty Server Implementation, maybe you have to handle reading/writing via ChannelHandlerContext more properly for example, instead of using `ctx.write()` `ctx.channel().writeandflush()` should be more proper way, also in closing usage of `ctx.channel().close()` or `ctx.channel().close().sync()` could make differences...

Comment: what is the difference between `ctx.writeAndFlush()` and `ctx.channel.writeAndFlush()`? my problem is netty always close the connection automatically after `writeAndFlush()` so the client cannot send another message to server.

Comment: They should be same in both ways they implement same ChannelOutboundInvoker interface though, for your problem i invest some netty example that might be useful https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/NettyExampleOfPingPongUsingObject

Comment: by the way i'm using netty.io (ver 4.x) and not jboss netty (ver 3.x), i don't know if they have significant difference. but thanks for the suggestion... oh, and i have tried to change `ctx.write(); ctx.flush()` into `ctx.channel().writeAndFlush()` but the socket still getting closed automatically.

Comment: No writeAndFlush doesn't solve your problem, you're right in your first comment code's logic it should be like write then flush for your case...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking for end of stream, so you are echoing it endlessly. `read()` returns a *value*. Check it. It returns -1 at end of stream. That's the end. Finis. Finito. Stop there. Don't print it. Don't keep reading. Do not pass GO. Do not collect $200.